# Why footer is good on some pages but on others not?

Tags: html, footer

My footer is well placed on some pages but on others it isn't. I did try to fit some suggestions offered on stackoverflow but did not work as it isn't the same issue. Thus, please do not downgrade this question.

An example for footer working well on some pages :

An example of bad footer, with white space above and bellow is this:

Even when doing drop down for Info tab, I have another page with the same bad footing space.

Here is the actual code I am working with:

```
 <footer class = "site-footer">
    <div class = "phs-purple-container">
   <div class = "container-inner-contents" id = "further-links-section">
    <!-- links to other profiling products -->
        <div class="col-sm-3">
        <img padding: 10px 10px; height="150px" src="www/bftb_logo_v8_bare.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
        <h4 style = "color:#d2cfeb" >Links</h4>
        <ul>
        <li><a style = "color:#d2cfeb" href="http:/bftb">test/bftb</a></li>
        <li><a style = "color:#d2cfeb" href="https://test.com/groups/430852910696122/">Workplace Group</a></li>
        <li><a style = "color:#d2cfeb" href="https://testics-for-the-Bench.aspx">Tutorial Recordings</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
        <h4 style = "color:#d2cfeb" >About us</h4>
        <p style = "color:#d2cfeb">The Bioinformatics for the Bench landing page was built by Gab under supervision of And and Jo. Please contact us with suggestions </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
        <h4 style = "color:#d2cfeb">Support</h4>
        <ul>
        <li><a style = "color:#d2cfeb" href="mailto:test.com">Contact Gab</a></li>
        <li><a style = "color:#d2cfeb" href="mailto:test.com">Contact And</a></li>
        <li><a style = "color:#d2cfeb" href="mailto:test.com">Contact Jo</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
</footer>
```

Can someone help me fix and understand the error?

Comment: Have you used F12 to see which element is adding the whitespace?

Comment: nope, and not sure if I use F12 it would help me. There are 3 pages that clearly are having issues with it. All the others don't. Do you have any suggestions how to solve this with a code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sadly none of the above answers work for me.

However I have solved it a bit differently. Indeed, the reason why I got those footers with so much space above and bellow, was that my content was too little on those pages compared to the other pages.

I have solved it but placing severals br(), br() into an R script I had written for each tab. For example, I have about us script (which fits into drop down menu from Info):

```
  about_us_tab <-
    
      tabPanel(
        "About Us",
        # value = "About Us",
        sidebarPanel(width = 1),
        mainPanel(
          width = 8,
          h3( style = "color:navy; font-weight: 600"),
          br(),
          br(),
          htmltools::htmlTemplate("www/about_us_tab.html"),
          br(),
          br()
        )
```

As you can see, I have put br()'s as much as I needed. And voila, the issue with different spaces on footer on different pages is solved!

Answer (score 1):

Your error here is that your footer by default just comes after the element before your footer. Without knowing your whole page, you'd tell the footer where to be placed. In Angular Material, they use the following CSS which should also work for you:

```
z-index: 9000;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
position: fixed;
```

Comment: where exactly this code should go?

Answer (score 1):

sorry for my bad english. btw, i think it is because the page where footer looks good have enough content and in which page not enough content there footer comes up. put this code just before that footer starts.

```
    <div class="container"></div>
<style>
.container{
min-height:800px;
}
</style>
```

you can adjust that 800px according to your page. This will set h minimum height for the container and footer will come after that container height.

Comment: @maio290  where exactly I shall put the code that you've written? Thanks for your response!

Comment: but how to correct this in the code section? It seems logic what you say but it has to be solved with a piece of code?

Comment: i guess that workflow heading is in a div. if it is, then try to give class="mb-5" and increase or decrease according to fit.

Comment: where I can put this piece of code - class="mb-5" , then?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).